# How to grant delete permissions on custom object for Customer Community user?

Tags: apex, community, permissions, customer-community

I have created a Customer Community. In there is a section where they can update their "skills", which behind the scenes is a `Contact_Skill__c` custom object holding that data.

I'm running into an issue where the Community user doesn't have permissions to delete the records in that object. I have checked/completed the following:

1. `Contact_Skill__c` has public read/write sharing settings.
2. Verified Community Sharing Set (may not be needed, but not available since public read/write).
3. Granted Read/Updated/Delete access to the Community user's profile for that object.

However, despite taking these steps, I'm still unable to delete these records using Apex. In my Apex code, I even check if the user has write and delete access before attempting to delete and according to the checks (`DescribeSObjectResult`) the user has that access.

The only thing I can thing I can think of is that Customer Community license doesn't allow deleting custom records. Is my assumption correct (hopefully not) or should I be able to delete custom object records as a Customer Community license user?

If I can delete custom object records, what else should I check to make sure my Community user has access to the delete the object?

Here's the error message (ID omitted, but points to the record I'm trying to delete):

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   {omitted}; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient
>   access rights on object id: []

Here's the CRUD settings for the Customer Community profile:

[image]

Here's the Sharing Setting for the `Contact Skill` custom object:

[image]

I also tried setting the Sharing settings to Public Read only, then creating a Community Sharing set, but still could not delete:

[image]

I'm attempting to delete the `Contact_Skill__c` records using APEX:

```
// get current contact skills
List<Contact_Skill__c> contactSkills = [select Id from Contact_Skill__c where Contact__c = :contactId];
// remove them
delete contactSkills;
```

Here's the controller signature:

```
public with sharing class InspectorCommunitiesController
```

This problem may be related to [this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210985/controller-action-returns-different-results-if-the-user-is-being-debugged).

Comment: is your query coming back with an/ list of ID(s) ? also include the contact__c in your query to show if the result set has contact skill with a contact associated with it. Even better system debug and make sure the contactId is same as the contact__c

Answer (score 2):

We have a customer community and users with the CC Plus as well as customer community login license are able to delete custom object records as long as their profile allows them do.

I dont think its a restriction of the license. There are restrictions for vanilla objects like account,contact for which these users cannot delete documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5).

But custom objects should be deleteable.

Comment: Thanks @RedDevil, what else should I check to make sure my Community user has access to the delete the object?

Comment: @SwisherSweet, can you add the error message to the question?.

Comment: @SwisherSweet,error says insufficient or read only. Are you sure the object has public read write settings in OWD?

Comment: Yes OWD has public read/write and profile has create/read/edit/delete.

Comment: do you have any other ideas why delete is not working despite confirming those things you suggested?

Comment: @SwisherSweet, How  are you deleting it through apex or UI?

Comment: the question has been updated with Apex code that's attempting to delete the records.

Comment: Just a vague though @SwisherSweet, can you check the  id for which it says in-sufficient access is it contact or contact skill?